# how to add newly created pkg path

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just build the redox package from [this](https://github.com/hmartiro/redox) page. Now how do i link the headers and libraries in ros cmakelist.txt file?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(pcl_visualizer_viewports)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} /home/rob/redox/include/)
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pcl_visualizer_demo pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcl_visualizer_demo ${PCL_LIBRARIES} /home/rob/redox/build/)
```

the error comming is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'redisAsyncHandleWrite'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhiredis.so.0.13: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer_demo.dir/build.make:367: recipe for target 'pcl_visualizer_demo' failed
make[2]: *** [pcl_visualizer_demo] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316441/how-to-add-newly-created-pkg-path/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2019-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is no different from any other system dependency. Please see whether the Catkin documentation on [system dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html) is clear enough.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0